# EF Core странно кешируется внутри Scope

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Поймал багу с Entity Framework Core 2.2 (Npgsql) и не могу понять, что происходит за кулисами, в чем и прошу помочь разобраться.

Рассмотрим для примера код:

```
using (var scope1 = Services.CreateScope())
{
    var db1 = scope1.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();

    var item1 = await db1.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    //Executed DbCommand: SELECT a."Id", a."Value" FROM "Items" AS a LIMIT 1

    item1.Value = "123";
    await db1.SaveChangesAsync();
    //Executed DbCommand: UPDATE "Items" SET "Value" = @p0 WHERE "Id" = @p1;

    // Представим, что этот using исполняется на другой машине
    using (var scope2 = Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var db2 = scope2.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();

        var item2 = await db2.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        //Executed DbCommand: SELECT a."Id", a."Value" FROM "Items" AS a LIMIT 1

        item2.Value = "qwe";
        await db2.SaveChangesAsync();
        //Executed DbCommand: UPDATE "Items" SET "Value" = @p0 WHERE "Id" = @p1;
    }

    item1 = await db1.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    //Executed DbCommand: SELECT a."Id", a."Value" FROM "Items" AS a LIMIT 1
    //Result: item1.Value = "123" - old value... =(
}
```

Проблема в том, что `db1` не видит изменения, которые были внесены через `db2`. Т.е. в консоли отладки я вижу, что `Executed: SELECT ... FROM "Items" AS a LIMIT 1`, но полученное значение `item1`  содержит старое значение `"123"`, вместо `"qwe"`.

Кстати,

- если использовать только один `scope`, то все нормально.
- или, если в последней строчке добавить `.AsNoTracking()`, то все нормально.

Это очень похоже на то, что данные просто закешировались, но в консоли то выводится, что запросы к базе таки идут...

#### Вопрос в следующем:

В результате работы данного кода, в БД физически отправляется пять SQL запросов (в том числе, последний `SELECT`). Так вот, что это за кеширование такое, при котором `SELECT` запрос отправляется, но его результат игнорируется? В моем понимании кеширование - это когда мы "помним" данные, чтобы НЕ делать лишних запросов. А тут наоборот. Должно же быть этому объяснение...

Comment: 1. Это не баг 2. Это неспецифично для постгре, то же самое будет и с другими базами.

Comment: Почему вы scope оборачиваете а using, а контекст бд - нет?

Comment: @AK - 1. Неправильно выразился... Имелся ввиду не баг в EF Core, а баг в моем приложении, возникший из-за специфики EF Core. 2. Я такого не утверждал =)

Comment: @tym32167 Если я не ошибаюсь, `scope.Dispose()` также освобождает все созданные им сервисы

Comment: Это было бы странно, держать ссылки на все созданные сервисы, даже если они не заявлены как синглтоны. Или в вашем примере может быть только одмн контекст на scope?

Comment: Не понял, вашего последнего вопроса... До этого вы спросили, почему не используется `using` для `DbContext`, я ответил, что в данном случае этого делать не нужно

Comment: Я работаю с nhibernate, там ситуация похожая. Так вот, там основная практика решения таких проблем - обеспечить возврат корректного контекста из GetRequiredService. В вашем случае должен был вернуться верхнеуровневый.

Comment: @Monk а мне кажется, что контекст вообще тут используется не по назначению. Не надо полагать, что он всё время синхронизирован с БД. Это же контекст БД. Я в приципе не могу представить реальной ситуации, когда один контекст надо создавать прямо во время жизни другого. Проще уж тогда вывести операции с БД в отдельный сервис, который либо оперирует одним и тем же контекстом, либо на каждый запрос создает контекст заново.

Comment: @tym32167 Это не важно. Важно лишь то, что это два разных контекста. Если вам так удобней, представьте, что `using (var scope2 = Services.CreateScope())` исполняется на другой машине другим сервисом.

Comment: Просто в моем представлении контекст БД - это такая штука, которая может спокойно кешировать что то, если нужна просто простойка между БД и клиентом, то юзайте dapper - он и быстрее и каждый раз запросы отправляет.

Comment: @tym32167 Все верно, это прослойка, которая может кэшировать что захочет. Но вопрос в том, почему она отправляет в БД последний `SELECT`, если данные все равно берутся из кэша? И раз запрос все же был отправлен и результат из БД получен, то почему бы ей не обновить свой кэш и не отдать актуальное значение?

Comment: А, в этом плане да, я бы тоже хотел узнать ответ - смысл вызывать БД на кешированную сущность, и если уж вызвали, но почему бы не обновить её.

Answer (score 0):

EF реализует паттерн UnitOfWork: ваш DbContext содержит набор репозиториев, вы можете к ним обращаться, чтобы читать и писать данные.

При этом EF "помнит" в каком состоянии находится база данных. Вы можете изменять данные в оперативной памяти, но реальное сохранение в базу данных происходит только тогда, когда вы запустите `.SaveChanges()`.

Это хранение состояния происходит на уровне экземпляра DbContext. Поэтому когда вы принудительно создали два разных экземпляра — то и изменения в них трекаются независимо.

Поэтому никакой ошибки Entity Framework в вашем коде нет, просто вы не в курсе, как это должно работать.

Если вы хотите отслеживание изменений — используйте один экземпляр. Приведённый вами пример является концептом для демонстрации, я думаю, что в вашем реальном коде нет никакой необходимости открывать второй scope, раз можно обойтись одним - либо не закрывая вовсе using, либо закрыть и тут же открыть новый. На практике такой пример как у вас стараются не допускать.

Вторая часть вашего вопроса о AsNoTracking. Дело в том, что указывая AsNoTracking вы (в качестве побочного эффекта, основное-то — не трекать изменения) заставляете взять не значение из "кеша", а прочитать из базы. (Не буду утверждать, что правильно понимаю механику, но мне кажется дело происходит примерно так: у вас есть как вы говорите "в кеше" одна запись, которая трекает изменения, когда вы просите создать нетреканную - она не берётся как копия уже имеющейся, а лезет в базу.)

В реальном коде я бы не стал полагаться на такую механику, потому что это нетривиально (может поломаться), да и предполагает, что программист хорошо понимает, что происходит под капотом. (иначе для того, кто читает этот код (а это можете быть и вы: через полгода уже не вспомните, что и зачем) будет казаться "магией").

Comment: Спасибо за жаждоутоляющий ответ, но я вроде не об этом спрашивал =) И писал я про ошибку "с" EF, а не "в" EF. И описанная ситуация абсолютно реальна, а не приведена для примера, и на практике встречается довольно часто, когда в БД вносятся изменения из нескольких компонентов\приложений\серверов. Мой вопрос был: почему, если данные кешируются, я тем не менее вижу в консоли отладки, что SQL запросы уходят к БД.